# Different git submodules on different Folders on the same git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I'll explain the mission.
I have a core git repository with my main software.
I have to use this software for different clients for which I have to specialize.

My goal is to have as many folders locally as my clients.
Within all folders I want to clone the CORE repository and I want to hook a submodule of specializations for that customer of that folder.

By doing so I can continue to make the core evolve even from different folders and at the same time I keep the specializations of the various customers distinct and isolated

I hope I explained myself, but I also leave an image for greater clarity

[image]

As an initial idea I had to manage a single local folder with the core and use the branches to specialize the various clients, but especially for Laravel I didn't want to versione the Storage folder so I find files from all the clients together.
That's why I would prefer to manage clients in separate folders locally

Comment: "*I want to clone the CORE repository and I want to hook a submodule of specializations for that customer of that folder.*" I see a problem in the setup: you cannot push back from any folder. Or you have to make a separate branch in every folder and add different submodules/subtrees. May be the solution is not to add real submodules but clone them locally as nested repositories and ignore them in CORE; this makes pushing back changes in CORE possible but not changes in CORE+subrepositories. Perhaps branches+submodules/subtrees+worktrees(folders) is the least problematic solution.

Comment: I was also thinking about subtrees, I've never used them, I'll give them a second thought.
thanks phd

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a different branch for each client, changing the submodules (defined in `.gitmodules`) appropriately in each branch.
2. When you're installing into `client A/` checkout the `client-a` branch and then do `git submodule update --init`.

Comment: Interesting...it might be the solution I'm looking for.
I try, thanks